# Question about a product installed in evaporator condensate drain pipe for flushing drain pipe

Tags: plumbing

I saw this product online. It installed inline with an AC condensate drain pipe to allow the user to flush the condensate piping by connecting a water hose to the shut off valve.

[image]

My question pertains to the tee on the right. The tee is 3/4" socket x 3/4" socket x [?]. I assume the part of the shut off valve threaded into the top of the tee should be a 3/4" male hose thread (MHT), and therefore, the threaded portion of the top of the tee should be 3/4" female hose thread (FHT).

The problem is, I cannot find any tee that is 3/4" socket x 3/4" socket x 3/4" female hose thread (FHT). I believe based on the part number barely visible (i.e., 402-00...) that it is a Spears product, but I could not find such a product in their catalog.

In other photos of the product, I notice a white residue where the shut off valve threads into the tee. I am not certain what that indicates (I'm assuming it's not pipe dope).

[image]

I am trying to build this product on my own by sourcing the materials. I have everything but the tee on the right. I'd like to find a tee that is 3/4" socket x 3/4" socket x 3/4" FHT so I can thread the shut off valve directly into the tee.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can buy a single piece like the right half of that product.  I guess I have to ask, if that product is what you want, why don't you just buy it?   Anyway, you can easily make *something like* the right half of that with an ordinary tee, another valve like the one on the left, a threaded fitting, and a thread to FHT adapter.   Those are all easy to find.   You could also adapt to FHT without the PVC valve then use a hose bib valve attachment.

I can't find an FHT to threaded adapter that *includes an integrated* valve like your one there, but if you're making this you don't need to do it that way.  MHT parts are marketed to DIY-ers but weird FHT parts like that are marketed to manufacturers (of things like lawn sprinklers) so it's not as easy to find them in web search.

From the Department of Unsolicited Advice: Pushing mains pressure water through your condensate line seems like a bad idea.  There's a reason pros use air for this task.  Condensate lines are not pressure tested, they are not built with a mindset of being blown out with water.  I've unfortunately seen them built without even gluing ... not that they should be built that way, but it happens and they work fine.  Until someone plugs a garden hose into one!

Comment: It's $50, so if I could make it myself, I wanted to go that route. I think I will use a 3/4" socket tee all around and then insert a 3/4" spigot x 3/4" FHT swivel fitting on the top. They had that at the store, but I was trying to replicate the design exactly if I could. Just wanted to double-check with the experts here before I went that route.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture I'd actually guess the arm of the tee is 1/2" FPT, and the hose-valve-fitting is 1/2MPT X FGHT - not that it particularly matters so long as the parts that connect match each other. A 1/2" connection should be plenty to flush out the line - the difference by using a 3/4" connection would be minimal, especially with typical garden hose that is not 3/4" itself.

The "white residue" clearly is either pipe dope or teflon tape. Plastic to metal there's going to be pipe threads.

Comment: I really think the thing OP is trying (a little too hard) to do is an FHTxMPT fitting with an integrated valve.  It's those *three* things that do not seem to be made together.  It's easy to do with *three* pieces.  But two?  I wonder if the product in OP's pitcure is an MHT fitting plugged into an FPT or even a plain socket using some kind of gunk-galore adhesive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to build the part on the right, you're looking for a 3/4 socket x 3/4 socket x 3/4 FPT fitting, e.g. Charlotte Pipe 402-007, plus a brass shut-off coupling, e.g. Orbit 58270.

Comment: The Orbit thing is MHT not MPT as needed.  The latter, *with* a shutoff, is more elusive.

Comment: Well whatever.  MPT-FHT valves are easily sourced.